# string compare if statements are being ignored

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, console, iostream

I am working on a strategy game to use with star wars battle front 2. It is a completely different program so you need to know nothing about the game to help me. all you need to know is how iostream works and string compare if statements.

```
`#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char Era[]="n";
    int eranumber=0;
    char* content [4] [28];
    char action[]="n";
    char whichplanet[]="n";
    char facilitytype[]="n";

//Jedi civil war
content [0] [0] ="Republic";
content [0] [1] ="Reavens Sith Empire";
content [0] [2] ="rectuitment center";
content [0] [3] ="rectuitment center";

content [0] [4] ="Alderaan";
content [0] [5] ="Bespin";
content [0] [6] ="Coruscant";
content [0] [7] ="Dagobah";
content [0] [8] ="Concord Dawn";
content [0] [9] ="Felucia";
content [0] [10] ="Geonosis";
content [0] [11] ="Harrun Kal";
content [0] [12] ="Hoth";
content [0] [13] ="Tatooine";
content [0] [14] ="Kamino";
content [0] [15] ="Kashyyyk";
content [0] [16] ="Methalyn";
content [0] [17] ="Mustafar";
content [0] [18] ="Mygeeto";
content [0] [19] ="Naboo";
content [0] [20] ="Ord Ilbanna";
content [0] [21] ="Polis Massa";
content [0] [22] ="Rattatak";
content [0] [23] ="Raxus Prime";
content [0] [24] ="Rhen Var";
content [0] [25] ="Utapau";
content [0] [26] ="Yavin";
// Great galactic war
content [1] [0] ="Republic";
content [1] [1] ="Sith empire";
content [1] [2] ="rectuitment center";
content [1] [3] ="rectuitment center";

content [1] [0] ="Coruscant";
content [1] [1] ="Dagobah";
content [1] [2] ="Alderaan";
content [1] [3] ="Felucia";
content [1] [4] ="Tatooine";
content [1] [5] ="Kamino";
content [1] [6] ="Kashyyyk";
content [1] [7] ="Mustafar";
content [1] [8] ="Mygeeto";
content [1] [9] ="Naboo";
content [1] [10] ="Polis Massa";
content [1] [11] ="Utapau";
//clone wars
content [2] [0] ="Republic";
content [2] [1] ="Sepratists";
content [2] [2] ="Cloning Facility";
content [2] [3] ="Driod Factory";

content [2] [4] ="Alderaan";
content [2] [5] ="Bespin";
content [2] [6] ="Coruscant";
content [2] [7] ="Dagobah";
content [2] [8] ="Felucia";
content [2] [9] ="Geonosis";
content [2] [10] ="Harrun Kal";
content [2] [11] ="Hoth";
content [2] [12] ="Tatooine";
content [2] [13] ="Kamino";
content [2] [14] ="Kashyyyk";
content [2] [15] ="Methalyn";
content [2] [16] ="Mustafar";
content [2] [17] ="Mygeeto";
content [2] [18] ="Naboo";
content [2] [19] ="Ord Ilbanna";
content [2] [20] ="Polis Massa";
content [2] [21] ="Rattatak";
content [2] [22] ="Raxus Prime";
content [2] [23] ="Rhen Var";
content [2] [24] ="Utapau";
content [2] [25] ="Yavin";
//Galactic civil war
content [3] [0] ="Rebel Alliance";
content [3] [1] ="Galactic Empire";
content [3] [2] ="rectuitment center";
content [3] [3] ="rectuitment center";

content [3] [4] ="Alderaan";
content [3] [5] ="Bespin";
content [3] [6] ="Coruscant";
content [3] [7] ="Dagobah";
content [3] [8] ="Concord Dawn";
content [3] [9] ="Felucia";
content [3] [10] ="Geonosis";
content [3] [11] ="Harrun Kal";
content [3] [12] ="Hoth";
content [3] [13] ="Tatooine";
content [3] [14] ="Kamino";
content [3] [15] ="Kashyyyk";
content [3] [16] ="Methalyn";
content [3] [17] ="Mustafar";
content [3] [18] ="Mygeeto";
content [3] [19] ="Naboo";
content [3] [20] ="Ord Ilbanna";
content [3] [21] ="Polis Massa";
content [3] [22] ="Rattatak";
content [3] [23] ="Raxus Prime";
content [3] [24] ="Rhen Var";
content [3] [25] ="Utapau";
content [3] [26] ="Yavin";
content [3] [27] ="Endor";

    cout <<"Select era (1.kotor,2.swotor,3.cw,4.gcw):";
    cin >> Era;
    if (strcmp(Era,"kotor"))
    {
        eranumber=0;
    }

    if (strcmp(Era, "swotor"))
    {
        eranumber=1;
    }

    if (strcmp(Era,"cw"))
    {
        eranumber=2;
    }

    if (strcmp(Era, "gcw"))
    {
        eranumber=3;
    }

    cout <<content [eranumber] [0]<< ", choose an action (1.Create facility, 2.Attack, 3.Create fleet)";
    cin >> action;
    if (strcmp(action,"create facility"))
    {
    cout<< "What type of facility(1.Mining site,2.)";
    cin >> facilitytype;
    if (strcmp(facilitytype,"miningsite"))
    {

    }
    }
    if (strcmp(action,"attack"))
    {
    cout <<"1."<<content [eranumber] [4]<<endl;
    cout <<"2."<<content [eranumber] [5]<<endl;
    cout <<"3."<<content [eranumber] [6]<<endl;
    cout <<"4."<<content [eranumber] [7]<<endl;
    cout <<"5."<<content [eranumber] [8]<<endl;
    cout <<"6."<<content [eranumber] [9]<<endl;
    cout <<"7."<<content [eranumber] [10]<<endl;
    cout <<"8."<<content [eranumber] [11]<<endl;
    cout <<"9."<<content [eranumber] [12]<<endl;
    cout <<"10."<<content [eranumber] [13]<<endl;
    cout <<"11."<<content [eranumber] [14]<<endl;
    cout <<"12."<<content [eranumber] [15]<<endl;
    cout <<"13."<<content [eranumber] [16]<<endl;
    cout <<"14."<<content [eranumber] [17]<<endl;
    cout <<"15."<<content [eranumber] [18]<<endl;
    cout <<"16."<<content [eranumber] [19]<<endl;
    cout <<"17."<<content [eranumber] [20]<<endl;
    cout <<"18."<<content [eranumber] [21]<<endl;
    cout <<"19."<<content [eranumber] [22]<<endl;
    cout <<"20."<<content [eranumber] [23]<<endl;
    cout <<"21."<<content [eranumber] [24]<<endl;
    cout <<"22."<<content [eranumber] [25]<<endl;
    cout <<"23."<<content [eranumber] [26]<<endl;
    cout <<"24."<<content [eranumber] [27]<<endl;

    cout<< "Select a planet to attack:";
    cin >> whichplanet;
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: just google `iostream` and `strcmp` ;)

Comment: `strcmp` statements aren't being ignored. They are working just as you programmed them to work. You are ignoring how `strcmp` works (;)). Check `man strcmp` and see what the return values mean.

Comment: I highly suggest using `std::string` instead of C strings. Also, **never** use a non-const `char *` to point to a string literal because those cannot be modified.

Comment: Strcmp returns 0 if the strings are equal, not 'true'

Comment: `strcmp` returns a number greater than zero, equal to zero or less than zero depending on whether the first string is greater than, equal to or less than the second string.  So, for your `strcmp` statements, you want to say `strcmp( xxx, yyy ) == 0` to determine if `xxx` equals `yyy`.  If you switch to using `std::string`, you can make this much easier, because then you can directly say `if (s == "value")` and the right thing happens.

Comment: Once you figure out how `strcmp` works you will want to fix a serious problem. All your input `char` arrays are __too small__ for the strings you are trying to read into them (you are trashing memory past the end of the arrays). I suggest you use `std::string` from the C++ standard library instead of raw `char` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` returns an `int` type of value not a `boolean` type.

So `strcmp` returns **0** if both the `strings` are same, otherwise it returns `+ve` or `-ve` number depending on the difference between the two `strings`.

So you need to write:

```
if (strcmp(Era,"kotor")==0)
{
    eranumber=0;
}

if (strcmp(Era, "swotor")==0)
{
    eranumber=1;
}

if (strcmp(Era,"cw")==0)
{
    eranumber=2;
}

if (strcmp(Era, "gcw")==0)
{
    eranumber=3;
}
```

Also remember `strcmp` is case-sensitive *(i.e. "A" is not equal to "a" according to this)*.
If you want to ignore the case then use `strcmpi` instead.

**NOTE:** 1 more thing `strcmp` and `strcmpi` both are defined in `<string.h>`

Comment: `iostream.h` hasn't been valid for a long time.

Comment: I am sorry if I am wrong. I am actually used to the Turbo C++ where we used "iostream.h", when I studied this in school. A lot might have changed since then. Ok, I will remove the first line then.

Comment: @KhurramHassan Your school owes you a refund. Turbo C++ is more than 20 years old so of course things have changed since then.